# How to make an app like Logo Quiz

Tags: android, database

I'm developing a Android app that functions like the popular Logo Quiz in the Google Play Store, however, I have not come across any tutorials on how to make the check mechanics.

I know it involves a database to determine whether the answer is correct or not but I do not know how to put it to use, any tutorials are welcome :)

Also I have everything else in the app set up apart from this but (The main bit -.-)

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial: http://www.anddev.org/android-tutorials-with-source-code-f39/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make an app like Logo Quiz you need to have some kind of relationship between logos name and it's picture. The first and the basic thing that I can think of it is just use sqlite database to store your logo name and image name. After that you can just check if it's correct after the user input.

At least that's the easiest way that I know.
However, it's just an idea so maybe there is better way to do this.

Comment: This sounds like a plausible way of doing it, thanks for your input, I'll be sure to comment whether its a success or not later on.

Comment: As an addition. Make sure you Upper or Lower their answer and keep a consistent naming for your names. Nothing is more annoying than having the answer be "pizza" but your input is "Pizza" and you get it wrong. Just a thought. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for that, I think I'll have it so the first letter is always upper case as most keyboards on phones do that automatically. Or I could make a app keyboard, it depends.

Comment: You can use `toLowerCase` for user's input, so you won't have any problems to check if it's the right logo name or not.